# What is the technical name for the type of security whose price updates once per trading day?

Tags: stocks, vanguard

For example, this guy right here:

[Vanguard Target Retirement 2050 Inv](https://www.google.com/finance?q=MUTF%3aVFIFX&ei=NjMxUdD8L6WyiQKKWA)

The price is updated once per day. What is this called technically? The reason I ask is because I'm building a system to track these and I want to classify these securities so I know I don't need to fetch their price every 15 minutes.

Comment: The answer is right on the webpage, it is a  mutual fund.

Answer (score 5):

*[Open Ended Mutual funds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_fund)* are not traded on the exchange market, the investors "buy" by investing into the fund directly, and "sell" by cashing out. There's no counter-party buyers/sellers. The price is determined based on the fund investments and evaluated daily. Hence the daily price changes.